# Uncover lstlisting on a particular slide using \onslide or \uncover

Tags: beamer, listings, overlays

**Updated:**

How can I uncover a certain `lstlisting` environment on a particular slide using `\onslide` or `\uncover`?

For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \onslide<1-> HI
  \onslide<2-> \begin{lstlisting} int i = 0; \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Verbatim material cannot appear in an argument to another command (up to a certain point you could try using an external file and inputting it with `\lstinputlisting`) and use `\uncover` on `\onslide`, but the best approach here is to use the `onlyenv` *environment* for your listing (since the frame contains verbatim material it requires the `fragile` option):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{3cm}
  \onslide<1->{Hi}
  \begin{onlyenv}<2->
  \begin{lstlisting} 
  int i = 0; 
  \end{lstlisting}
  \end{onlyenv}
\end{overlayarea}  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I also added an optional `overlayarea` environment to prevent possible "jumps". An animation of the result:

[image]