# Using verbatim within a onslide environment

Tags: beamer, verbatim, overlays

I want to use `\onslide<2->` with verbatim environment inside in beamer, e.g.:

```latex
\onslide<2->{
\verb+foo+
}
```

This does not work due to overlays and verbatim conflicts... I found out that there is a [`onlyenv`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274721/beamer-only-and-lstlisting-do-not-work-together/274725#274725) environment that fixes the issue for `\only` but I cannot find anything for `\onslide`.

Is there some equivalent to `onlyenv` for `onslide`?

Comment: Do you try to add to frame  option `fragile`: `\begin{frame}[fragile]`?

Answer (score 0):

According to, e.g., this answer: [Uncover lstlisting on a particular slide using \onslide or \uncover](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271243/uncover-lstlisting-on-a-particular-slide-using-onslide-or-uncover), there is no such equivalent, and I also could not find any. You can user `\onlyenv` with an overlayarea environment to avoid jumps due to overlay animations. This however forces you to initially fix the dimensions of the animated area, which you don't have to when you're using `\onslide`...

I sometimes resort to creating overlays with external programs. My currently preferred solution is Inkscape + the TexText plugin + [this script I developed](http://www.dominic-steinhoefel.de/2018/11/14/extract-inkscape-layers-to-pdf-files-for-latex-beamer-presentations/) which crates you several PDF from layer specifications and provides you with a snippet to include in your LaTeX file. Sometimes it's just nice to have a graphical editor, even when you like to use LaTeX.